# Can I change Apache configuration based on requestHeaders?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, http-headers

I need to configure filter settings (In Apache2) based on RequestContent header. Is it possible?

Specifically changes based on the value of one header.

(I'm using mod_line_edit to filter html in reverse proxy)

EDIT:
I'm doing reverse proxy and I want to filter out some tags (I can do that with mod_line_edit) I only want to apply this rules when there is specific RequestHeader present.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, and if it were it would be a ***REALLY BAD IDEA*** -- Allowing you to change configuration settings on a server by magic in the client's request headers would be a pretty serious security hole.

Perhaps if you can tell us more about what you're trying to do someone can suggest a less painful way of accomplishing it?

Comment: I tried to improve my question